# Mojolicious - minion worker doesn't start automatically

Tags: perl, mojolicious, job-queue, hypnotoad

I am using [Mojolicious](https://mojolicious.org/) full app and loading [Minion](https://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Minion) (backend sqlite).
My question is why minion worker doesn't start by itself when I start mojolicious app with [hypnotoad](https://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojo/Server/Hypnotoad). According to the documentation [Minion](https://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Minion) it should:

> Background worker processes are usually started with the command
>   Minion::Command::minion::worker, which becomes automatically available
>   when an application loads Mojolicious::Plugin::Minion.

#### Environment:

- Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server  - 7.5 (Maipo)
- Perl v5.16.3
- Mojolicious 8.0 (Supervillain)
- Minion 9.01

#### Mojolicious full app

```perl
package Apps;

use Moo;
extends 'Mojolicious';

sub startup {
    my $self = shift;

    $self->plugin(Config => file => '/var/www/apps/lib/appconf.perl');
    $self->plugin(Minion => {SQLite => 'sqlite:/var/www/apps/db/minion_backend_sqlite.db'});
    ...
}
```

**This is how I start my server:**

`/usr/local/bin/hypnotoad /var/www/apps/script/apps`

**Currently, I start [minion](https://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Minion) worker in background( which also gets killed somehow after sometime, starangely) like this:**

`/var/www/apps/script/apps minion worker -m production`

Thank you.

Comment: The documentation only suggests that the _command_ becomes available, but I think you're still supposed to start the worker yourself. Most likely the worker stops after some time when there is no more work to be done, but you should look into its log for that

Comment: Thanks @Corion. I got confused by documentation as the minion command is available even when hypnotoad is not running. I mean `/var/www/apps/script/apps minion worker -m production` still runs fine when app is not run. I am not sure if there is log for minion. However, looks like log for hypnotoad suggests that workers were stopped gracefully after sometime:

Comment: example worker being stopped: `[Fri Dec 14 13:59:24 2018] [info] Stopping worker 9716 gracefully (120 seconds)`

Comment: The hypnotoad log is referring to Mojolicious workers. Minion workers are separate unrelated processes, that you must start and manage on their own.

Comment: Thank you. I thought there might be some way to manage Minion automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Corion and Grinnz mentioned in comments:

> Minion workers are separate unrelated processes, that you must start
>   and manage on your own.

#### Good news:

Mojolicious team has opened this issue. Will be solved soon:
[Allow for Minion worker to be started by the application server](https://github.com/mojolicious/minion/issues/76)

Answer (score 0):

Using `Mojo::IOLoop::Subprocess` you can start a subprocess within the app like this:

```
my $subprocess = Mojo::IOLoop::Subprocess->new;
$subprocess->run(sub {...}, sub{...})
```

Documentation [here](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::IOLoop::Subprocess#run)

That means that you can use the `before_server_start` hook to start worker subprocesses via `app->minion->worker->run`

Once they've started though there seems AFAIK no easy way to stop them when the app itself stops, so you have to check them and reap them - which is where [Proc::ProcessTable](https://metacpan.org/pod/Proc::ProcessTable) can help.

I've put all this together in a quick and dirty plugin [here](https://gist.github.com/simonecesano/5da478e8c9f52dfa70d5e5cfe101eb10).